# Issue with Selma updating entity from Dto withIgnoreNullValue field type Date

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapper

I am using Selma for mapping my Object from Dto to entity include update entity from Dto, when i add (withIgnoreNullValue = true) to my mapper, I don't why he doesn't ignore the null value of fields Type date. when I check my generate class mapper I found this

```
if (inDto.getStartDate() != null) {
        out.setStartDate(new java.util.Date(inDto.getStartDate().getTime()));
      }
      else {
        out.setStartDate(null);
      }
```

Comment: did you found the solution for this, i'm in the same situation and I need to ignore the mapping to destination object

Comment: Please, be more specific with your question. What is the expected generated code for your scenario? From "he doesn't ignore the null value of fields Type date" I understand that, if `inDto.getStartDate()` is null, it should be ignored. From my point of view, the generated code is correct.